# Rollback Visual Studio WebApplication to a previous working state

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, rollback

I built an asp.net MVC project and it was working perfectly. I played with it a little more, and doesn't work anymore. Is there a way to rollback the application?

Comment: Darin is correct, Source control is really essential. Although depending on your OS, you may be lucky and restore a previous version of the folder your solution is in. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/previous-versions-files-faq#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Consider asking a SO question seeking assistance with the specific problem you are now having with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you used some sort of version control system such as [`GIT`](http://git-scm.com/), there's no such functionality built-in that would allow you to revert back to some previous state of your code. I would strongly recommend you using version control for all your projects.

Comment: Microsoft makes a free Express version of their Team Foundation Server as well. It can be cumbersome, but also includes other features that can make it compelling in addition to source control.